# Is it possible to connect MySQL Proxy with H2?

Tags: mysql, database, proxy, compatibility, h2

I want to reach a load balancing for a lot of servers running H2. 
My idea was to use MySQL Proxy, because it allows read-write-separation, fail over or other customized balance options with the help of LUA. 
My goal is to combine it with H2 using the MySQL compatibility mode of H2. Does anybody know if this is possible to connect it with H2? 
With kind regards, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

There are only Servers with H2 protocol and PostgreSQL protocol, so I think it is not possible in the moment, isn't it?